# iPhone popover controller present view controller fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using a third party popover controller on the iphone and have ran across an issue. The one I'm using is [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) but have tried using [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) and it has the same "issue" since they work in a similar way. Here is the deal:

I have a notifications button in my app which pops up a popover controller which contains the notifications feed. It's like the Facebook app. You can see it on the below image.

[image: Popover in action]

Now what I want to do it so present a view controller on top of everything and in full screen. The way that popover controller works is that it ads its view directly to the applications main window and its not nested in the view hierarchy so I get a warning saying `presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged` and it does not present full screen as well (I know thats logical). If I present it on the parent view controller (the red one in the background) it gets presented below the popover view.

**How to fix this?**

I was thinking about using a new `UIWindow` instance and using a root view controller there. Is this an OK solution or is it a hack? If it's ok then how do I accomplish this? I want the presentation and dismissal to be animated :)

I want it to look like Facebok Paper app when you tap an item in the notifications feed.

Comment: Why not dismiss the popover before presenting on the "red" parent view?

Comment: Because when I dismiss the detail controller I want the popover to stay visible. Presenting it again without transition seems like a hack. And considering the fact that I want the transition to be interactive the popover must be visible as the user will slide the screen down to reveal what is underneath it (you get the idea, it's like a card).

Comment: Technically, using `WYPopoverController` is a hack. That's why it has to add the views directly to the window- so that it can overlay things like the nav bar and still show up properly in the view.

Comment: How to implement this the right way then? I want the logic for activity feed in a separate view controller so that is nice and separate.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure. You can look into awarding a bounty to add extra interest to your question.